# Request being sent to wrong PORT while sending for from frontend to backend using axios

Tags: node.js, axios, package.json

My frontend is running on PORT 3000 whereas backend on PORT 3000. I am making requests using axios in my frontend. So to avoid CORS error I tried setting

"proxy":"http://localhost:5000/"

but still the request is being sent to port 3000. How to get my request to port 5000?

I was expecting my request to be forwarded to PORT 5000.

const { data } = await axios.get(`api/chat`, config);

I made this request.

and got this error : GET http://localhost:3000/api/chat 404 (Not Found)

the request should have been made http://localhost:5000/api/chat

Comment: what are you using `vitejs` or `reactjs` or `nextjs`

Answer (score 0):

Run your frontend to port 3000, and backend at port 4000, and mention proxy to frontend/package.json file which has to mention the `"proxy": "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:4000"`